# Is it a good builder?

Tags: java, builder

There is a class which has many fields and all of them are required. The java code is like:

```
public class MyCls {

    private String aaa;
    private String bbb;
    private String ccc;
    private String ddd;
    private String eee;
    private String fff;
    private String ggg;

    public MyCls(String aaa, String bbb, String ccc, String ddd, String eee, String fff, String ggg) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
        this.bbb = bbb;
        this.ccc = ccc;
        this.ddd = ddd;
        this.eee = eee;
        this.fff = fff;
        this.ggg = ggg;
    }

    // here are getters for all fields, no setters
}
```

The caller code will be:

```
new MyCls("111","222","333","444","555","666","777");
```

My friend said it's not easy to find the meaning of each parameter, so create a builder for it. This is the code:

```
package builder;

public class MyClsBuilder {
    private String aaa;
    private String bbb;
    private String ccc;
    private String ddd;
    private String eee;
    private String fff;
    private String ggg;

    public MyClsBuilder setAaa(String aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
        return this;
    }

    // similar code for 'bbb','ccc',...,'ggg'

    public MyClsBuilder setGgg(String ggg) {
        this.ggg = ggg;
        return this;
    }

    public MyCls createMyCls() {
        return new MyCls(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg);
    }
}
```

The caller code will be:

```
    MyCls cls = new MyClsBuilder()
            .setAaa("111").setBbb("222").setCcc("333")
            .setDdd("444").setEee("555").setFff("666").setGgg("777")
            .createMyCls();
```

Ok, we can see what setter we used for each parameter, it's clearer. But I have a question:

Do we really need such a builder? I can't see much benefit.

In fact, if we add setters for the original code, we can write similar code without creating a new class:

```
MyCls cls = new MyClsBuilder();
    cls.setAaa("111");
    cls.setBbb("222");
    cls.setCcc("333");
    cls.setDdd("444");
    cls.setEee("555");
    cls.setFff("666");
    cls.setGgg("777");
```

The only difference is is's not a chain.

And to use that `MyClsBuilder`, I have to worry about if I forget to call any `setX` by mistaken.

```
MyCls cls = new MyClsBuilder()
        .setAaa("111").setBbb("222").setCcc("333")
        .setDdd("444").setEee("555").setFff("666")
        .createMyCls();

// forget to invoke `.setGgg("777")`
```

But with the "constructor" one, there is no such problem since the compiler will check it for me.

So I don't think a builder a good solution, is it any better one?

Comment: Using builder when all parameters are required is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In fact, if we add setters for the original code, we can write similar code without creating a new class

Yes, but only if `MyCls` is mutable. Sometimes you want an immutable object, which will have no setters.

> And to use that `MyClsBuilder`, I have to worry about if I forget to call any `setX` by mistake.

Builders are less useful if all of the arguments are required. Builders are very useful if there are lots of arguments and most of the arguments can be made *optional*, because the builder can initialize them with defaults.

With a plain constructor, implementing optional arguments requires several overloaded constructors (confusing), or for users to specify defaults for the arguments they don't care about (distracting). A builder makes this easier because you only need to specify the couple of settings you care about.

Answer (score 1):

This is to address Freewind's observation that the simple counter method doesn't cater for accidentally setting a parameter twice. For clarity I've used a bit set but an int counter could be used in the same way, however the bit set is probably more elegant and less cryptic.

```
private BitSet parameterBits = new BitSet(7);  // there are 7 parameters

public MyClsBuilder setAaa(String aaa) 
{
    parameterBits.set(0);  // set bit position 0 to true
    this.aaa = aaa;
    return this;
}

public MyClsBuilder setBbb(String bbb) 
{
    parameterBits.set(1);
    this.bbb = bbb;
    return this;
}

public MyClsBuilder setGgg(String ggg) 
{
    parameterBits.set(6);
    this.ggg = ggg;
    return this;
}

public MyCls createMyCls() 
{
    if ( parameterBits.cardinality() < parameterBits.length() )
    {
        throw new Exception("Not all parameters supplied.");
    }
    return new MyCls(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A disadvantage / problem with the constructor version is that in your particular case you could accidentally swap two parameters around. With a builder this is less likely to happen.

A builder can still be used if all of the arguments are required, it just takes a bit more code to check that all the parameters have been supplied.

A simple way (but not necessarily the best way) for instance is to have counter that increments when a parameter is set:

```
private int counter = 0;

public MyClsBuilder setAaa(String aaa) 
{
    counter++;
    this.aaa = aaa;
    return this;
}

public MyCls createMyCls() 
{
    if ( counter < 7 ) throw new Exception("Not all parameters supplied.");
    return new MyCls(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg);
}
```

So builders I would say are less error prone and more readable. And clear code is good code :-)

Comment: For the `counter` version, what if user missed 'setGgg' but write `setFff` twice?

Comment: @Fre An excellent observation. Like I said its simple, but not the best as you point out. See next answer for a solution :-)